# Boas práticas para URI em API RESTful

Tags: api, rest, restful

Estou com dúvida em relação às URIs de alguns recursos da api que estou desenvolvendo. Tenho os recursos **projetos** e **atividades** com relação **1-N**, ou seja, um projeto tem várias atividades e uma atividade pertence à um projeto.

Qual a forma correta ou a melhor forma em relação às convenções REST? Gostaria de alguns exemplos para requisições `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` e `DELETE` para estes recursos.

**EDIT:** Reformulei a pergunta.

Comment: Gostaria de acrescentar que a Microsoft publicou um guideline para APIs,  o conteúdo está disponível aqui: [github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se o projeto **tem** atividades, eis a forma correta de representar, diferenciando o `PUT` de `PATCH`. Como entendo que haverá o recurso `/projetos/` e apenas o `/atividades/` para o GET, vou organizar os possíveis endpoints pelos métodos HTTP.

## GET

- Buscar todos os projetos: `GET /projetos/`
- Buscar o projeto de número 1: `GET /projetos/1`
- Buscar todas as atividades do projeto 1: `GET /projetos/1/atividades`
- Buscar a atividade 1 do projeto 1: `GET /projetos/1/atividades/1`, mas uma opção também é apenas criar um `/atividades/1`.
- Buscar a atividade 1: `GET /atividades/1`
- Buscar todas as atividades: `GET /atividades/`

## POST

- Criar o projeto de número 1: `POST /projetos/`, passando no body da request as informações do projeto
- Criar uma atividade no projeto de número 1: `POST /projetos/1/atividades`, passando no body da request as informações da atividade

Você também poderia ter um `POST /atividades/1`, passando o número do projeto no body. Esta decisão vai depender de como quer representar os recursos disponíveis. Esta "quebra" pode ser feita quando o seu endpoint começa a ficar muito extenso ou acredita que ele ficará melhor organizado. Se for optar pela quebra, o ideal é manter a coerência e também fazer a mesma quebra nos outros métodos HTTP do recurso.

## PUT

Utilizado para substituir um recurso **inteiro** existente por outro.

- Substituir **todo** o conteúdo do projeto de número 1: `PUT /projetos/1`, passando no body da request todas as novas informações do projeto
- Substituir **toda** uma atividade de número 1 no projeto de número 1: `PUT /projetos/1/atividades/1`, passando no body da request as novas informações da atividade

## PATCH

Utilizado para alterar apenas uma ou algumas informações específicas do recurso.

- Atualizar qualquer informação do projeto de número 1: `PATCH /projetos/1`, passando no body da request apenas as informações do projeto que gostaria de atualizar
- Atualizar qualquer informação de uma atividade de número 1 no projeto de número 1: `PATCH /projetos/1/atividades/1`, passando no body da request apenas as informações da atividade

## DELETE

- Remover o projeto de número 1: `DELETE /projetos/1`
- Remover uma atividade de número 1 no projeto de número 1: `DELETE /projetos/1/atividades/1`.

O `DELETE` também pode ser usado quando o sentido é uma exclusão lógica do recurso, pois às vezes o pessoal só associa este método ao `DELETE` do banco de dados, o que não faz sentido.

Lembre-se também de [retornar códigos HTTP que sejam coerentes](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Exemplo: 201 para criação de um recurso via `POST`, 200 ou 204 no `PUT` e `DELETE`, 404 para quando não encontrar o recurso, etc.

Comment: "Buscar a atividade 1 do projeto 1: GET /projetos/1/atividades" - Faltou o número da atividade: "GET /projetos/1/atividades/1"

Comment: Então tem mesmo que usar essa hierarquia. E se eu quisesse buscar todas as atividades independente do projeto eu poderia usar `GET /atividades` ou `GET /projetos/atividades`? E quando eu quiser exibir um único atributo de atividades, por exemplo numa tela de projetos eu preciso exibir somente o nome da atividade, devo usar outro método, certo? Já que `GET /atividades` ou `GET /projetos/atividades` me retornaria todos. Obrigado.

Comment: @FernandoZabin Para sua primeira pergunta, seria `GET /atividades/`. Para a segunda pergunta, se você tem uma atividade 1 e deseja pegar informações dela, eu recomendo usar `/atividades/1` ou, se você tem o projeto já e deseja pegar a partir dele, pode ser também `/projetos/1/atividades/1`, mas recomendo o `/atividades/1` mesmo.

Comment: @FernandoZabin, editei minha resposta para ficar mais claro

Comment: @Dherik, ficou bem claro. Mais uma dúvida, eu tenho uma tabela onde exibo todas as atividades e em uma coluna dessa tabela exibo o código do projeto ao qual ela pertence. Nesse caso eu usaria `GET /atividades`, mas e se projeto tivesse 20 atributos (chaves) e eu preciso somente do código, eu criaria outro método http ou usuária `GET /atividades` mesmo e traria todas as informações? Pergunto isso pensando em desempenho ou para evitar trazer muitas informações. Abusando um pouco mais, como ficaria um método para trazer atividade por nome e data? Muito obrigado pela resposta, ficou excelente.

Comment: @FernandoZabin, não me preocuparia com performance logo no início, o REST é bem leve. Se isto **realmente** for necessário, não conheço algo no REST que te diga como fazer. Uma solução que você poderia implementar é fazer algo como `/atividades?fields=id,nome`. Assim, o `GET /atividades/` retornaria as informações padrão (todas) e quando passar o `fields` ele retornaria apenas os campos listados. Para trazer por nome e data, você usaria GET `/atividades?nome=Joao&data=2016-10-26T13:43:10Z` , sendo a data no formato ISO 8601 de preferência (e em UTC, de preferência também).

Answer (score 4):

Poderia utilizar a seguinte abordagem:

```
get /projetos # Lista de projetos    
post /projetos # Criar um projeto

get /projetos/1 # Buscar o projeto com id 1
put /projetos/1 # Atualizar o projeto com id 1
delete /projetos/1 # Deletar o projeto com id 1

get /atividades # Todas as atividades
post /atividades # Criar nova atividade

get /atividades/1 # Atividade com id 1
put /atividades/1 # Atualizar atividade com id 1
delete /atividades/1 # Deletar atividade com id 1

get /projetos/1/atividades # Lista de atividades do projeto com id 1
```

Lembrando a RFC 5789, o método put seria para substituir um recurso. Use o patch para modificá-lo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241893/rest-api-patch-or-put

Pode conferir nestas perguntas, sobre design das URI

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038943/restful-api-uri-design

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833548/hierarchical-restful-url-design

Comment: Entendi, eu estava fazendo dessa forma, mas vi alguns exemplos que me deixaram confuso, vi algo parecido com `GET /projetos/1/atividades // Criar nova atividade`. Assim fica mais fácil de entender. Obrigado, Matheus. Ps: tinha esquecido sobre o patch, valeu!

Comment: Corrigindo meu comentário: `POST` no lugar de `GET`.

Comment: @FernandoZabin, você quase entendeu certo da primeira vez. Se você deseja criar uma nova atividade para um projeto, você deve usar **POST** (e não GET) para `/projetos/1/atividades`, pois a atividade é do projeto, correto? Ter este conceito em mente é muito importante no REST. Veja minha resposta.

Comment: Caso o POST fosse feito em /projetos/1/atividades, então teria que seguir como a resposta do @FernandoZabin mesmo, representar a hierarquia na URI, neste caso as URI podem acabar bem longas. Imagine que agora cada atividade tem um atributo item com suas propriedades, para seguir o padrão ficaria /projetos/1/atividades/1/itens. E se surgir um novo atributo em item?

Comment: @MatheusSilva, ficaria assim mesmo. Se não fizer assim, você vai precisar passar, no seu exemplo, o id da atividade dentro do body do POST em /items/, o que pode ficar meio confuso depois. Mas, se ocorrer o caso de ter muitas URLs longas, é uma alternativa boa a sua.